# ga_session_id is unique identifier on Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I checked the official docs here:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en

[image]

But, when I checked my data, there are several user_id and user_pseudo_id in one ga_session_id.
How is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

`ga_session_id` is not supposed to be globally unique (afaik it's based on a skewed in-device timestamp) but in most circumstances (except for edge cases) it should be locally unique for a given `user_pseudo_id`

Comment: This is the correct answer. A composite key with `user_pseudo_id` and `ga_session_id` can be considered a unique session Id in a dataset/property.

Answer (score 7):

**session_id** is not unique (two or more users can have the same session_id).

It is just timestamp when the session started, so we need to concat session_id and **user_pseudo_id** or **user_id**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the query used, with this I see the unique values associated correctly in my data:

```
SELECT event_timestamp, user_id, user_pseudo_id, event_name, event_params.value.int_value AS session_id 
FROM `MYTABLE`,
UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params
WHERE event_params.key = "ga_session_id" LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same query, but there are several user_pseudo_id in a certain session_id. So... there is something wrong with my Google Analytics, right?